# How do I use Count to count how many rows exist for each player

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the Lahman Baseball Database, http://seanlahman.com/files/database/readme2012.txt, and trying to figure out how to count how many distinct teams a player has played for so I can use that as a sub query to find the players who have played only for the Los Angeles and Brooklyn Dodgers

This is what I have so far, I know its not right cause its giving me wrong results

```
SELECT  M.masterID, M.nameFirst, M.nameLast, A.teamID, count( DISTINCT A.teamID) as numberOFteamsPlayedfor
from master as M, appearances as A
where M.masterID = A.masterID
group by A.teamID
```

This is the two tables I am working with right now

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBpn.png)

These are the table structures

```
CREATE TABLE "master" (
 "masterID" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 "birthYear" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "birthMonth" int DEFAULT NULL,
  "birthDay" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "birthCountry" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 "birthState" varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 "birthCity" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 "deathYear" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "deathMonth" int DEFAULT NULL,
"deathDay" int DEFAULT NULL,
"deathCountry" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
"deathState" varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
"deathCity" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
"nameFirst" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
"nameLast" varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 "nameGiven" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 "weight" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "height" float DEFAULT NULL,
  "bats" varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  "throws" varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 "debut" datetime  DEFAULT NULL,
"finalGame" datetime  DEFAULT NULL,
"retroID" varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
"bbrefID" varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("masterID")
);
 CREATE TABLE "appearances" (
 "yearID" int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 "teamID" varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 "lgID" varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 "masterID" varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 "G_all" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "GS" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_batting" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_defense" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_p" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_c" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_1b" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_2b" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_3b" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_ss" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_lf" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_cf" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_rf" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_of" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_dh" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_ph" int DEFAULT NULL,
 "G_pr" int DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY ("yearID","teamID","masterID")
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"count( DISTINCT A.teamID)" & "group by A.teamID" is redundant so your count is grouping twice.   Change "count( DISTINCT A.teamID)" to "count(A.teamID)" and GROUP BY will take care of it for you.

Comment: I have tried that but its giving me wrong results, I am pretty sure Hank aaron didn't play for 1950 different teams

Comment: Try GROUP BY M.masterID. I'm going a bit blind without being able to see the table structure,...but that will give you each individual player instead of each individual team.

Comment: I have tried that also but its still giving wrong results, says hank aaron played for 23 different teams. I added the table structure to my question

Comment: Ah, it's "by year and by team",...so Hank Aaron playing for 23 seasons with 1 team each season makes sense and the DISTINCT in the count makes sense. If you throw that back in, but keep the new GROUP BY you should be in fat city.